# ADFS 2.0 unable to parse SAML authentication request from SF

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have set up SSO according to the instructions in [this](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services) article. The org is using my domain and the login starts from MYORG.salesforce.com

The SAML Authentication request is going out successfully from SF to ADFS but then ADFS throws the following error when trying to parse the request:

```
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request.

Additional Data
Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: ID4037: The key needed to verify the signature could not be resolved from the following security key identifier 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = Microsoft.IdentityServer.Tokens.MSISSecurityKeyIdentifierClause
    )
'. Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.ResolveSigningCredentials()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.OnEndOfRootElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.EnvelopedSignatureReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadSamlMessage(XmlReader reader, NamespaceContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage)
```

My understanding is that this error occurs because the key signature on the SAML request does not match the certificate that ADFS has for SF. This was imported from download metadata button on the single-sign on settings so it should be correct.

Comment: All I can suggest is to double check the configuration. Perhaps you disabled/enabled SAML on the SF side, causing the cert to be regenerated? Have you enabled multiple configs on the SF side? Are you using the correct metadata?

Comment: @metadaddy, There's only one SAML configuration. I will try enabling/disabling SAML to re-generate the cert and re-install to ADFS.